# <Lists> emptying themselves

Tags: java, list, for-loop

Good evening,

I am having a weird issue with a method I am trying to implement on Java. 
I will try and describe it as well as possible:

Basically what it does is checks for the next states an Epsilon-Non Deterministic State Machine would reach, given a state and an array of possible transitions. 
The method "loadEpsilon(List)" loads up the possible epsilon transitions for the given list of states.

```
      if (transitionList.isEmpty()){
          return new HashSet<State>(stateEntryList);
      }
      else{
          for (int i=0; i <= transitionList.size()-1; i++){
              for (int j=0; j <= stateEntryList.size()-1; j++){
                  for (Transition tr : this.transitions()){ 
                      if ((tr.fromState() == stateEntryList.get(j)) && (tr.label() == transitionList.get(i))){
                          if (!stateExitList.contains(tr.toState())){
                              stateExitList.add(tr.toState());
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
              stateEntryList.clear();
              stateEntryList = loadEpsilon(stateExitList);
              stateExitList.clear();
          }
          return new HashSet<State>(stateEntryList);
              }
```

So, filling up the whole code with tracing "System.out.print"s right to the very end, just before the

```
    stateExitList.clear();
```

everything is OK. However, past that line, I print BOTH lists RIGHT after that sentence (StateExitList and StateEntryList) and they are both GONE.

I just can't figure out why they are emptying themselves.

Any chance for help?

Thanks a lot in advanced.

EDIT: This here would be the code for loadEpsilon:

```
  public List<State> loadEpsilon(List<State> states) throws NoInitialStateException{
      State stateRead;
      if (states.isEmpty()){ 
          if (this.getInitialState() == null){
              throw new NoInitialStateException();
          }
          states.add(this.getInitialState());
          return loadEpsilon(states);
      }
      else{
          for (int i=0; i <= states.size()-1;i++){
              stateRead = states.get(i);
              for (Transition tr : this.transitions()){
                  if ((tr.fromState() == stateRead) && (tr.label().isEpsilon()) && (!states.contains(tr.toState()))){
                      states.add(tr.toState()); 
                      System.out.print(states.size());
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return states; 
  }
```

The declaration of the lists are the following:

```
      List<State> stateEntryList = new ArrayList<State>();
      stateEntryList = loadEpsilon(stateEntryList);       
      List<State> stateExitList = new ArrayList<State>();
      List<Label> listaLabels = new ArrayList<Label>();
      listaLabels.addAll(Arrays.asList(labels));
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're calling `clear()` on both lists, which will empty both lists. Your question is "why are both lists empty"? Either I am very confused, or you are.

Comment: you are clearing the stateEntryList and stateExitList N times (once for each transitionList item). I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @Travis Webb: No, I used clear() precisely to empty both lists.

Comment: @Mohamed Nuur: 
I am clearing the lists N times so that the list it uses on the inner loops is empty. However, I would like that after the LAST element in transitionList, the lists wouldn't empty themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `stateEntryList` is empty after you call `stateExitList.clear()` after you call `loadEpsilon`, that points toward the `List` that `loadEpsilon` returns being somehow tied to the `stateExitList` being passed to it.  Perhaps the list that `loadEpsilon` is returning is using the list passed to it as a backing store or something like that?  You really need to  post the code to `loadEpsilon`.

---

**Edited:**

Well that explains it.  your `loadEpsilon` is returning the `List` that was passed to it.  It is returning the exact same object it was given.  So you're ending up with the same object being referred to by two names.  But since it's the same object underneath, when you clear it, it's cleared.

You're basically doing this:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("foo");
list1.add("bar");

List<String> sameList = list1;
sameList.add("quux");

list1.clear();
```

Does that make it clearer why clearing one list clears them "both"?  (Again, there's only one object there that is being referred to by two reference variables).

Comment: I just edited the code with the `loadEpsilon()` code included.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had literally crammed a `print` in between every code line to see where the thing was emptying my lists, but didn't realise it could've been that :)

Comment: Yes, yes. That makes it very clear. I guess instead of using the `=`, I'll just use the `addAll()` method to avoid this kind of behaviour. 

Thanks again :)

Comment: EDIT: After testing the `addAll()` I can safely say it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Lists do not *spontaneously* empty themselves in Java.  Trust me.  It doesn't happen.

This means that there must be a different explanation:

- Maybe the two lists are actually the same object, or views on the same object.  So clearing one list clears the second one.
- Maybe clear is being called on the second list somewhere else, and you haven't spotted it.  Or maybe it is happening as a result of remove / removeAll calls.
- Maybe the second list was already empty.  For instance, where you thought you were adding to the second list you were actually adding to an entirely different list object.
- Maybe you are using a custom list implementation that has broken behaviour; e.g. some other operation is effectively deleting things as a mistaken side-effect.
- Maybe it is something else ...

We are not going to help you with this without all of the relevant code (with the traceprint code included) and the output from the traceprints.

Comment: Oh, I spent some time clearing all the traces thinking that it would only clutter it for you guys here :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I'll try and post questions in a much more detailed manner next time.

Answer (score 0):

Is `loadEpsilon` using deferred execution?  That would explain why emptying the list passed to it would result in the list it returns being empty.

Comment: I'm so sorry but, what does Deferred Execution mean? 
However, when printing the list AFTER the loadEpsilon and BEFORE the last stateExitList.clear() they both appear as they should (containing the correct elements). 

It is only when I clear the stateExitList that they both dissappear.

Comment: "Deferred Execution" means that a method doesn't do its work when it is called.  Instead, it may create a thread that does the work at some arbitrary future time.  So if you cleared the list before the actual work was done, there could be a problem.  However, given what you've said it doesn't sound like deferred execution is being used.

Comment: I'm not sure about Java, but in C# you can use iterator blocks to return a different sequence given an input sequence.  The iterator block doesn't iterate over the input sequence until your code begins iterating over the output sequence.  In this way you could set up a transform, and then clear the input list, and when you iterate over what you think is the output list there's nothing there because iterator block used in the transform doesn't have anything to iterate over anymore.

Comment: Thank you both for your explanation, apparently it wasn't Deferred Execution, but at least I got to learn what it is :)